# Android app deploy on eclipse creating duplicate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, duplicates

Whenever I Run an Android app on my phone (even when the application has not been installed before), the application is shown duplicated in the app drawer. This started happening right after I setup a Splash Screen activity, and I find it kind of annoying. One of the apps in the launcher install *with* the SplashScreen Activity, the other one does not. The app works without issues, but is there a way to remove this duplicate app icon in the drawer?

It's not urgent, but maybe you guys know ;)
I run my Android app projects with Eclipse, if it's of any help.
Any ideas? Oh, and if you guys need me to show you some of my code, please tell me.
I followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/) tutorial for the creation of my splash screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to only have this:

```
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

at one Activity, in your manifest.xml

Comment: I had, indeed, two activities with the second line.